# Nginx full page cache using Memcached/Elasticache and purging with PHP

Tags: php, caching, nginx, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I have a PHP application running on the latest Nginx.  I would like to cache each full page for a specific URL using memcached and also have the ability to purge/invalidate a specific cached page with a few PHP commands.

My research suggests using these 2 modules:
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSRCacheModule
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMemcModule

Is that the best/easiest way?  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [built-in Memcache module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_memcached_module.html) The configuration is straight forward:

```
server {
    location / {
        set            $memcached_key "$uri?$args";
        memcached_pass host:11211;
        error_page     404 502 504 = @fallback;
    }

    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass     http://backend;
    }
}
```

The cache invalidation isn't straight forward and if possible use short TTL that forces cache to be unobtrusive and invalidate by time. Otherwise look for Memcache practices [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322709/php-memcache-design-patterns).

Comment: Thanks.  When a page is served that is not in the cache, will it automatically be inserted into the cache or will I have to do that manually?

Comment: @Littlebob manually via backend, standard Nginx Memcache module is read-only.

Comment: Here is a similar question with a partial similar answer  http://serverfault.com/questions/342548/configuring-nginx-to-work-with-memcache-for-reverse-proxy-cache

Comment: @Littlebob yes, this is similar 4 years old question and the solution is still remain the same